# Manually installed exiv not found during meson build in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, compiling

Can anyone explain the following?

```
user@system:~/gexiv2-0.11.0/build$ exiv2 --version

exiv2 0.27.1

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public
License along with this program; if not, write to the Free
Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor,
Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA


user@system:~/gexiv2-0.11.0/build$ meson --prefix=/usr ..

The Meson build system
Version: 0.49.0
Source dir: /home/user/gexiv2-0.11.0
Build dir: /home/user/gexiv2-0.11.0/build
Build type: native build
Project name: gexiv2
Project version: 0.11.0
Native C compiler: cc (gcc 8.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0")
Native C++ compiler: c++ (gcc 8.3.0 "c++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0")
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.13.4)
Dependency exiv2 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

meson.build:13:0: ERROR:  Dependency "exiv2" not found, tried pkgconfig

A full log can be found at /home/user/gexiv2-0.11.0/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

given that exiv2 version 0.27 does not exist for Ubuntu in general (it stops at [v0.25](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=exiv&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all)).

I did the following:

1. I went to [the exiv website](https://www.exiv2.org/download.html)
2. I grabbed the link for the linux build of exiv 0.27
3. I ran the following

   ```
   wget https://www.exiv2.org/builds/exiv2-0.27.1-Linux64.tar.gz
   sudo tar xzf exiv2-0.27.1-Linux64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib/
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```
4. added `:/usr/local/lib/exiv2-0.27.1-Linux64/bin`
5. `source /etc/environment`
6. restarted the terminal.

and then exiv is correctly usable.

But meson does not detect it is there during the build.

To be clear: the package gexiv2 Version [0.10.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gexiv2&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all) shipped for Ubuntu 19.04 is inferior to my needed version of 0.11.0 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong - you have downloaded binary version of Exiv2, but really you need source version with corresponding headers and development files.

So the complete steps will be the following:

### exiv2 part

```
sudo apt-get install cmake meson
sudo apt-get build-dep exiv2

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.exiv2.org/builds/exiv2-0.27.1-Source.tar.gz
tar -xf exiv2-0.27.1-Source.tar.gz
cd exiv2-0.27.1-Source/
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Check:

> ```
> $ exiv2 --version | head -n1
> exiv2 0.27.1
> ```

### gexiv2 part

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgexiv2-dev
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gexiv2/0.11/gexiv2-0.11.0.tar.xz
tar -xf gexiv2-0.11.0.tar.xz
cd gexiv2-0.11.0/
meson build
cd build
sudo meson install
```

and so on.